# Using jQuery to detect if element has a certain style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I'm writing a script to detect whether or not an image is present on a webpage. It's a standard formatting with their html for this section. If there is *not* an image it looks like

```
    <div id="photo" style="display: none;">
       <img id="image" src="IMAGESOURCE" onerror="img2txt()" alt="">
    </div>
```

if there *is* an image present that same html looks like this

```
    <div id="photo">
       <img id="image" src="IMAGESOURCE" onerror="img2txt()" alt="">
    </div>
```

Right now in the script I'm using this, which doesn't work (or i wouldn't be here :D )

```
  var images = ($('#photo[style*="display: none"]').length === 0 ? false : true);

    if (images) {
      $('#yes[value="Yes"]').click();
    }
    else {
      $('#no[value="No"]').click();
    }
```

(The clicks are for the radio buttons on the form that I am filling out based on this image query)

As of right now the if/else statement is giving the radio "No" a click on a page where it should be a yes. I've tried using

```
    if (!images) {
      $('#yes[value="Yes"]').click();
    }
    else {
      $('#no[value="No"]').click();
    }
```

just to see if my boolean was incorrect. But with that adjustment it just does the opposite again. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should drop the attribute selectors..

Comment: `$('#yes').prop('checked', $('#image').is(':visible'))`

Comment: `$('#no').prop('checked', !$('#image').is(':visible'))`

Answer (score 1):

So it is always `display:none` when not present? jQuery has a specific selector for that `:visible`.

```
var present = $("#photo").is(":visible");
```

Comment: It is always display:none when not present... that line of code isn't working for this though...

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether the image is visible or not:

```
$('#image:visible').length;
```

With reference to your own posted code, you could use:

```
var imageVisible = $('#image:visible').length,
    toClick = imageVisible ? 'yes' : 'no';

$('#' + toClick + '[value=' + toClick + ']').click();
```

Or, avoiding the unnecessary attribute-selectors (given that an `id` is a unique identifier:

```
$('#' + toClick).click();
```

References:

- [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector).

Comment: I'm not sure why but this isn't working. Also, the id's are actually the same for the yes/no radio buttons (i wrote the html from memory, oops), so the attribute selectors need to stay. But I would think the first suggestions would work... no luck though

Comment: In what way is it not working? Where does it fail? And if the `id` of two separate elements are the same then your JavaScript will break, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: It's acting the same as before, either Yes for every page or No for every page depending on how I write the if statement  if (!images) vs if (images) . Also, I went and double checked again, but the id's for the radio button inputs are the same... I did not write the html for that.

Comment: Then you'll need to post your HTML for us to help.